# Создать две даты (вчера и сегодня)

Tags: sql, дата

Необходимо создать две даты, с учетом рабочих дней. Скажем, шесть рабочих дней.

Сегодня и вчера, но если вчера воскресенье, то суббота (вчерашний рабочий день)

Я создала некий запрос:

```sql
DECLARE @DATESTART DATETIME = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @DATESTART) = 7 --ЕСЛИ ВОСКРЕСЕНЬЕ
BEGIN
SET @DATESTART = @DATESTART - 1
END
DECLARE @DATEEND DATETIME = @DATESTART - 1
IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @DATEEND) = 7 --ЕСЛИ ВОСКРЕСЕНЬЕ
BEGIN
SET @DATEEND = @DATEEND - 1
END

SELECT @DATESTART AS D1, @DATEEND AS D2
```

Результат:

[image: Результат]

Процедура, где я использую даты, ничего не возвращает. А когда я пишу вручную даты `('23/11/2023' и '22/11/2023')`, то работает. Правильно ли я создала запрос?

Запрос сама писала по документации, и семь, насколько я поняла — это индекс воскресенья.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @DATESTART DATE = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @DATESTART) = 7 --ЕСЛИ ВОСКРЕСЕНЬЕ
BEGIN
    SET @DATESTART = DATEADD(day, -1, @DATESTART)
END
DECLARE @DATEEND DATE = DATEADD(day, -1, @DATESTART)
IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @DATEEND) = 7 --ЕСЛИ ВОСКРЕСЕНЬЕ
BEGIN
    SET @DATEEND = DATEADD(day, -1,@DATEEND) 
END

SELECT @DATESTART AS D1, @DATEEND AS D2
```

Объяснение:

При `SET @DATEEND = @DATEEND - 1` вы точно уверены как неявно вычисляется ваше значение? Я - нет. Используйте `DATEADD` для операций с датами

Comment: как вы делаете отступы ? в sql или вручную ?

Comment: С помощью TAB в SQL Management Studio

Comment: вручную то есть, а есть ли возможность (как в визуал студио ctrlK ctrlD к примеру)типа выделил код и поправил, я имею ввиду, есть ли автоматическое форматирование по нормам ? И есть ли нормы вообще по написанию sql ? у меня всегда в ряд все

Comment: Никогда об этом не задумывался. Погуглил в VS Code можно использовать SQL Formatter. В связке с работой с БД в VS Code, получится то, что вы хотите. В среде майков, подобный функционал я не нашел

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519876/sql-formatting-standards вот полезная ссылка тоже пусть тут будет